# Convert non numeric values as numeric when they are displayed as numbers

Tags: sql, numeric

I am using ISNUMERIC to get all non numeric rows in my table - but all I get in return is the following example  1.437.230,61  or  3.511.980,00. I really dont know how to get these few rows converted to numeric! I have conveted about 2,5 mil rows without problem but I am getting about 9000 rows that are not numeric - but as displayed above they are numbers. I have tried to trim my coloumn with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should always name the dbms you are using. Many dbms have problems converting proper numbers such as  1.437.230,61 due to the thousand separators. So isnumeric works fine here, but the conversion function doesn't.

Use a string replace function to remove the thousand separators from the string before converting. Such as:

```
to_number( replace(numstr, '.', '') )
```